# Activating broadcom wireless drivers in CLI

Tags: 10.10, server, command-line, wireless

The wireless card as identified by lspci:

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) which addresses my issue exactly. I've got internet connectivity and I just want to enable the wireless card on this old Dell laptop. However, I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.10 and I would rather not install a Desktop. Thus, I'm stuck at the following step:

> Step 2.
>
> Under the desktop menu System >
>   Administration > Hardware/Additional
>   Drivers, the b43 drivers can be
>   activated for use.

Is it possible to accomplish this in the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with some help from a user in `#ubuntu`. Apparently there's a bug in the b43-fwcutter package that prevents the drivers from actually being loaded. Following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a clue about package's name you can use `apt-cache` to search among packages.So search for **b43**:

```
sudo apt-cache search b43
```

Output is:

```
b43-fwcutter - Utility for extracting Broadcom 43xx firmware
```

For me on ubuntu 10.04.So I can install it with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I've done this - first step in the guide I posted above but I'm getting this with iwlist scan: `wlan0 Failed to read scan data : Network is down`. lsmod also seems to come up clean: http://pastebin.com/LkjSsm8t. I should mention that the laptop has no external wifi switches - just a Fn key combo that I've toggled every time I test something.

Comment: Oh, Sorry for my mistake.Did you see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access?

Comment: I did but I'm following the "Internet Access" portion of the guide since I've got it hooked up via ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

If is no present, you need also **wpasupplicant** in order to have wpa and wpa2 support 
(see `apt-cache show wpasupplicant`) and set /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

Can you show me `lshw -C network`?

If is ok:

1) sudo ifdown eth0

2) sudo ifup eth1 (or similar)

3) sudo ifconfig eth1 IP_static_your_machine netmask 255.255.255.0

4) sudo route add default gw adress_of_your_gateway_(like 192.168.1.0) eth0

Comment: Something feels off here: http://pastebin.com/h2vdrKMq

Comment: Also, here is my /etc/network/interfaces: http://pastebin.com/r7AHYDJY.

Comment: So, seems ok for me... Have you try to perform the top operation indicated?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the driver from [this link](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz).

And follow the instructions [here](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt).

It works on the Ubuntu kernel version 2.6.X